# Rails migration for altering existing database view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration, database-view

I have a view named `my_view` which I created using the following migration.

```
class CreateMyView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      drop view if exists my_view
    SQL

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
      SELECT 
        t1.wfs_id,
        t1.step_id,
        t1.status,
        t1.applied_by,
        t2.created_at,
        t2.is_wfs_end,
        t2.app_status AS flowstep
       FROM table1 t1
         JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.wfs_id = t2.wfs_id
      WHERE t1.del_flag = false;
    SQL
  end
end
```

now I need another field, say `my_new_field` from `table1` to be available in `my_view`. But I have no Idea how to write the migration for this. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about simply recreating the view:

```
class ChangeMyView < ActiveRecord::Migration   
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      drop view if exists my_view
    SQL

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view AS 
      SELECT 
        t1.wfs_id,
        t1.step_id,
        t1.status,
        t1.applied_by,
        t1.my_new_field,
        t2.created_at,
        t2.is_wfs_end,
        t2.app_status AS flowstep
      FROM table1 t1
        JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.wfs_id = t2.wfs_id
      WHERE t1.del_flag = false;
   SQL 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

The [scenic](https://github.com/thoughtbot/scenic) gem (by thoughtbot) will help you a lot in managing your views!